# Why is there no save button on the Google OAuth Consent Screen setup page

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth

[image: Just what the question is all about]

I tried changing every damn setting, I don't need a verified screen, I have done this before and it worked flawlessly, but I don't know what is wrong now

There is no save button here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data from the previous screen are automatically saved. On the summary, and only if your app use protected API scope, you can ask for verification on this latest screen:

[image]

Comment: My use case didn't need any scopes to be added, so I went to firebase console ( it was for an electron app, with firebase ) and enabled Google Sign-in and it worked. I still don't understood what happened though